# Grammar behind "Trump Calls Quits On Paris Climate Deal"

Tags: grammar, headlinese

We have the following headline:

> Trump Calls Quits On Paris Climate Deal

What part of speech is 'quits'? Is it a verb or noun?
What are the words left out and what is the grammar in general behind this?

Comment: [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/quits) and most other dictionaries list the word specifically.

Comment: It's "headlinese" (missing out the word **it**). Compare [*call it a day*.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/call+it+a+day)

Comment: It's a mistake; the idiom has to be calls it quits. They should have written: leaves

Comment: There is no grammar behind headlines other than using the fewest words to convey the barest sense of what the article is about to the target audience. Don't get hung up on headline grammar.

Comment: @Lambie - It looks fine to me – for a headline. [This](http://soccer.nbcsports.com/2017/05/20/philipp-lahm-calls-quits-on-tremendous-bayern-munich-career/) is [not](http://www.stuff.co.nz/entertainment/tv-radio/88926523/Peter-Capaldi-calls-quits-on-Doctor-Who) the [first time](https://planetradio.co.uk/kiss/entertainment/music/iggy-azalea-calls-quits-instagram/) that [this shortcut](https://www.slashgear.com/nintendo-reportedly-calls-quits-on-wii-u-production-01462346/) has [been taken](http://www.sports-powa.com/stoudemire-retires-after-14-years/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example of *headlinese*

> Trump Calls Quits On Paris Climate Deal

"*quits*" is an *adjective*, and the missing bits are

> Trump Calls *(It)* Quits On *(The*) Paris Climate Deal

Comment: Yes, and it really should be: call it quits or leaves. Calls quits is really not acceptable, even in a headline. It sounds awful.

Comment: @Lambie, "quits" is more inflammatory than "leaves", which attracts more eyeballs.  The objective is to sell papers or attract views--clickbait.

Comment: Note also that in headlinese, the past tense is written as simple present tense (this headline isn't saying that Trump is in the process of "calling it quits" but that he already did so).  Even more bizarrely, future tense is written as a simple infinitive (i.e. "[subject] **to [verb]** [object]").  Overall, headline grammar is quite atypical of English.